# Can I connect a c++ application to a database like FireBase?

Tags: c++, database, firebase

I recently got into databases and I wanted to know if it is possible to connect a simple program like this to a database (I use Firebase) to store data like names and passwords. Thank you for the help!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string name;
    int password;

    cout << "Insert name: " << endl;
    cin >> name;
    cout << "Insert password: " << endl;
    cin >> password;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends on where this C++ program is executed.

- If it is executed on Android or iOS, the answer is yes and you can follow the process outlined in [Add Firebase to your C++ project](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cpp/setup).
- If your code is running on a desktop machine on Windows, macOS, Linux, you can use [parts of Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cpp/setup#libraries-desktop) by following the process outlined in [Set up a desktop workflow (beta)](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cpp/setup#desktop-workflow).

Comment: Hi! Yeah, my program is a c++ console application that is running on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Yes! You can try to follow this https://firebase.google.com/docs/cpp/setup